# React Native - TextInput caret position resets when toggling the secureTextEntry prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a component that should be used as wrapper of React Native `TextInput` in my app. I've created a visibility toggle to display or not the password. When I change the `secureTextEntry` prop, the caret position of my `TextInput` resets to 0.

I've tried to hotfix the problem using a state to store caret position and a ref on the `TextInput` component to call setNativeProps after toggling on/off the `securedTextEntry` prop.

**Here is my component:**

```
export default class AppTextInput extends React.Component<Props, State> 
{
  static defaultProps = {
    defaultValue: '',
    icon: '',
    keyboardType: 'default',
    secureTextEntry: false,
    style: {},
    styleTI: {},
  };


  state = {
    isPasswordHidden: true,
    // State used to track cursor position
    selection: {
      start: 0,
      end: 0,
    },
  };

  // Update state when selection changes
  handleSelectionChange = ({
    nativeEvent: { selection },
  }: {
    nativeEvent: { selection: { start: number, end: number } },
  }) => {
    this.setState(() => ({ selection }));
  };

  tooglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isPasswordHidden: !prevState.isPasswordHidden,
    }));
    // Set the caret position back to its previous location and not 0
    this.textInputRef.setNativeProps({
      selection: { start: this.state.selection.start, end: this.state.selection.end },
    });
  };

  // Reference of the TextInput (typed with Flow)
  textInputRef: React.ElementRef<TextInput>;

  render() {
    const {
      callbackFromParent,
      defaultValue,
      icon,
      keyboardType,
      placeholder,
      secureTextEntry,
      style,
      styleTI,
    } = this.props;
    const { isPasswordHidden, selection } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ ...styles.textInputView, ...style }}>
        <Icon color="#000" name={icon} size={20} style={styles.icon} />
        <TextInput
          // Reference of the TextInput
          ref={textInputRef => (this.textInputRef = textInputRef)}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          onChangeText={text => callbackFromParent(text)}
          // Method to handle selection changes
          onSelectionChange={this.handleSelectionChange}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          placeholderTextColor="black"
          secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry && isPasswordHidden}
          // State to use for the selection
          selection={selection}
          style={{ ...styles.input, ...styleTI }}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        />
        {secureTextEntry && (
          <Icon
            color="#000"
            name={isPasswordHidden ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'}
            onPress={this.tooglePasswordVisibility}
            size={20}
            style={styles.icon}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18377 Found this issue on react-native GitHub too...

Answer (score 0):

I bumped someone's PR on Facebook React Native GitHub, a cherry-pick has been done for the realease of version 0.59.5! Bug fixed!